# Как связать определенный месяц с определенным ключом?

Tags: python

Долго ломаю голову, но никак не могу понять, что я делаю не так.

Есть файл с датами типа:

```
16 Октября 2014 19:21
16 Октября 2014 18:46
16 Октября 2014 18:41
16 Октября 2014 17:18
```

.......

```
from DATEspliter import DATE
dates=[]
o = open('date.txt').readlines()

for elem in o:
    dates.append(elem)
    d = DATE(elem)
    if d.Month() == ['Октября']:
        date = {str(d.Clock()[0]):elem.strip()}
        Year['okt'][int(d.Day()[0])].update(date)

    if d.Month() == ['Сентября']:
        date = {str(d.Clock()[0]):elem.strip()}
        Year['spt'][int(d.Day()[0])].update(date)
```

Есть словарь Year с ключами 'okt', 'spt'...
Нужно определённый месяц запихнуть в подопределённый ключ.
Всё бы хорошо, но мой код либо один октябрь в оба словаря пихает, либо и октябрь, и сентябрь в оба, как не пробовал. Хотя если выводить elem в каждой if, то "сеет" их правильно. Функция print это доказывает.

Comment: @smilemakc, из описания не очень понятно, что происходит, приведите пример некорректного вывода на вышеописанный ввод.

Скорее всего, у вас где-то элементы октября и сентября ссылаются на один и тот же объект, но точно об этом сказать сложно.

Comment: @Etki,
если в первом if вставлять
 
    print(d.Month())

покажет все ['Октября'],

если во втором if вставлять
 
    print(d.Month())

покажет все ['Сентября'].

Но по итогу print(Year['okt']) и print(Year['spt'])
дают идентичные выводы, где есть и октябрь, и сентябрь. 

Вывод большой, в коммент не помещается, вот ссылка на txt: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_cnSxTxOHUud1RHNGhjRDNXTW8/view

Comment: Откуда Year['spt'] и Year['okt'] берутся?

Comment: @Etki

вот от сюда
http://hashcode.ru/questions/368236/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%B2-python3

Comment: Для отладки поможет небольшой входной текст (который содержит и Сентябрь и Октябрь) и соответствующий отформатированный пример (pprint) ожидаемого вывода, и что вместо этого получается.

Код очень тяжело читать. Методы Month, Clock, Day должны возвращать сами величины, а не списки, чтобы не использовать `[0]` везде. Стоит упомянуть почему `DATE` используется вместо `datetime` из стандартной библиотеки. Идеально привести небольшой самодостаточный скрипт, который демонстрирует проблему и который можно запустить отдельно (например, использовать datetime.date чтобы избежать зависимости от DATESpl

Comment: Более традиционные аббревиатуры для Сентября, Октября: 'Sep', 'Oct', а не 'spt', 'okt':

    >>> for month in range(1, 13):
    ...     print(datetime.date(1, month, 1).strftime('%b'))

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не сделать вот так:

```
dic_my={
1:'январь',
2:'февраль',
3:'март',}
```

Разве не решение проблемы?

Comment: Словарь в данном случае не нужен, можно простой список использовать: `month_names_ru = [None, 'январь', 'февраль', 'март',..]`. Можно ещё посмотреть на `calendar.month_name` из стандартной библиотеки в русской локали.